# PHP email form is coming through without spaces between words and no special characters

Tags: php, ajax, email

I have built a form that sends using the php mail function via AJAX. My problem is when my emails come through, all spaces are replaced by '+' and special characters are replaced by things like '%40'.

Here is my AJAX script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.builderForm').each(function() {
            $(this).on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                var loading = '<div id="overlay"><img id="loading" src="<?php echo LAYERS_FORM_BUILDER__PLUGIN_URL;?>assets/images/loading.gif"></div>';
                $(loading).appendTo('body');
                $.ajax({
                        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                        url         : '<?php echo LAYERS_FORM_BUILDER__PLUGIN_URL;?>includes/class-send-form.php', // the url where we want to POST
                        data        : {'formData' :formData}, // our data object
                        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                        encode      : true
                    })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        // log data to the console so we can see
                        //console.log(data); 
                        setTimeout(function(){$('#overlay').hide();}, 4000);
                        $('#overlay').remove();
                        $('.successMsg').html("Message Was Sent Successfully!!");
                        setTimeout(function(){$('.successMsg').hide();}, 5000);
                        // Reset form after submission
                        $(".builderForm")[0].reset();
                    });

                event.preventDefault();

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my PHP mail handler code:

```
$layers_email_address = '';
$layers_email_subject = '';

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if (!empty($errors)) {
// if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;

} else {
    parse_str($_REQUEST['formData'], $formFields)
//$formFields = explode('&', $_REQUEST['formData']);
$html='<html><body>';
foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
    $fields = explode('=', $key);
    $field = $fields[0];
    $value = $fields[1];
    $html .= '<p><label>' . $key . ' :</label> ' . $value . '</p>';
}
$html .='</body></html>';
$to = "sam.skirrow@gmail.com";
$subject = "Form Submission";
$txt = $html;
$headers = "From: <sam.skirrow@gmail.com>". "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"."\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

// if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

// show a message of success and provide a true success variable
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

How can I make it so that my emails come through as pain text, rather than special characters being ommitted?

Issue presented with multiple checkbox data sending, here is the code to dynamically create checkboxes (it sits in a foreach statement and takes each line of the "select-options" text area in the widget to populate each checkbox

```
if ($item['input_type'] == 'checkbox') { ?>
    <div class="options_container">
        <?php foreach(explode("\n", $item['select_options']) as $select_option) { ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $item['input_name']; ?>" value="<?php echo preg_replace('/\s+/','', $select_option); ?>" <?php if( $this->check_and_return( $item, 'required') ) { echo 'required'; } ?>><span class="checkbox_option"><?php echo $select_option; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Edit: New code for php mail handler:

```
$layers_email_address = '';
$layers_email_subject = '';

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if (!empty($errors)) {
// if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;

} else {
    parse_str($_REQUEST['formData'], $formFields)

$html = '<html><body>';
foreach ($formFields as $key => $value) {
    $html .= '<p><label>' . $key . ' :</label> ' . $value . '</p>';
}
$html .= '</body></html>';
$to = 'sam.skirrow@gmail.com';
$subject = "Form Submission";
$txt = $html;
$headers = "From: <sam.skirrow@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);

// if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

// show a message of success and provide a true success variable
$data['success'] = true;
$data['message'] = 'Success!';
}

// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is what you looking for.

---

Use `parse_str($_REQUEST['formData'], $formFields)`] instead of `$formFields = explode('&', $_REQUEST['formData']);`

This will parse your string `$_REQUEST['formData']` for create an array with `key => value` in the variable `$formFields`.

Documentation of the function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

**EDIT:**

For the foreach working you will need to do this :

```
foreach ($formFields as $key => $value) {
    $html .= '<p><label>' . $key . ' :</label> ' . $value . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work - however when my email comes through I now loose the $field - so my email is just a list of results, wheras before it was $field : $value - now it just comes through as $value :

Comment: Instead of `foreach ($formFields as $key)` use foreach `($formFields as $key => $value) {` so you will get the $key and the $value of your array.

Comment: I see, that didn't work though, I just get the $key and not the $value - let me update my code so you can see what I've written - pretty sure it's what you are saying though

Comment: No emails are sending now - Ive updated my code so you can see what I've added

Comment: You don't need this lines : `$fields = explode('=', $key);
    $field = $fields[0];
    $value = $fields[1];`

Comment: Computer just crashed, will check after reboot and let you know

Comment: Sorry for late reply, computer crashed, lost my work - have just pieced it back together. Yes this works, but with one bug. When sending checkboxes data, if more than one checkbox is selected, only the last one sends via email. I.e. if I have Check box 1, Checkbox 2 & Checkbox 3 selected in a form, only checkbox 3 sends

Comment: The `name` of your checkbox is the same ? If yes that's why just the last checkbox appear in the `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Yes you are right - is there a way to dynamically add different names to my checkboxes? They are formed in an array - I'll add it to my question so you can see

Comment: Ok, I see your update. When you create `$item['input_name']` why you set the same name ? You can't change it ?

Comment: No I haven't created the interface for the user to be able to change the name of each checkbox (I think it will be too confusing for a user who isn't used to making forms) - is there a way I could add an incremental value to each checkbox - so it's essentially $item['input_name']+1...

Comment: Yes it's possible you can do this `foreach(explode("\n", $item['select_options']) as $i => $select_option)`. And replace `$item['input_name']` by `$item['input_name'].$i`. You will get : nameYouSet0 & nameYouSet1 & etc.

Comment: That is perfect thank you - I need to get my head around foreach statements better - weekend reading I think!

Comment: For some reason this has just stopped working - not sure what I've done - can you see if I've made an error - new php handler code is in my question

Comment: You forget a `;` at this end of line : `parse_str($_REQUEST['formData'], $formFields)`

Comment: No it's happen sometimes.